# PyInstaller to executable file in lunx, giving : error running upx -v?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pyinstaller

I tried to get executable file using PyInstaller on Linux terminal but its throwing **error running upx -v**. I tried with both .**py** and **.spec** file but same error

Same process i tried on windows its worked fine.

I am using :

**1. Python : 3.5.7**

**2. PyInstaller : 3.5.**

For more details pleas find check below image

[image: See Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used below command and its worked

```
pyinstaller myfile.py --upx-dir=..\upx391w -y --onefile
```